# Order items horizontal in XAML GridView (Win8 / Metro)

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-8, microsoft-metro

how can i sort the items of GridView horizontal in the XAML?
Sadly i found no method to achieve this. The Keyword "Orientation" is not available.
Here is my current GridView:

```
            <GridView x:Name="TestDataBinding"
                HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                SelectionMode="None"
                ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource itemTemplateSelector}"
                Margin="0,60,0,0"
                Width="1100" Height="540"
            />
```

Another Way could be a "VariableSizedWrapGrid". But this can't be used for creating Items through "ItemsSource" (and ItemTemplateSelector).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sorry, I have to take issue with your comment that this cannot be done with a VariableSizedWrapGrid. It most certainly can:

```
<GridView>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <x:String>One</x:String>
    <x:String>Two</x:String>
    <x:String>Three</x:String>
    <x:String>Four</x:String>
</GridView>
```

And I have to take issue that VariableSizedWrapGrid cannot be used for creating items through ItemsSource. It **most** certainly can. WrapGrid and VariableSizedWrapGrid are fundamentally identical. WrapGrid is slightly lighter weight since it does not support Column and Row spanning.

Answer (score 5):

Add an ItemsPanelTemplate to control how the items are arranged, for instance,

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set the orientation of the ItemsWrapGrid:

```
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <ItemsWrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

Comment: This is better because this keeps drag and drop intact.