# How can I add a control to a GridView when an item is selected such that the control is on the row below the selected item and spans all the columns?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I have a GridView with a [horizontal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14260632/order-items-horizontal-in-xaml-gridview-win8-metro) orientation.
When the user selects an item in the GridView I would like to show a list (of child objects) between the row of the selected item and the row below the selected item.  The list should span all the columns of the GridView.

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding SrGroups}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ServiceReviewGroupTemplate}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Disabled" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Auto">
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal"></WrapGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>

<DataTemplate x:Key="ServiceReviewGroupTemplate">
    <Grid Background="{StaticResource BlueMedium}" Height="150" Width="150">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Margin="10,0,10,10" Text="{Binding Name}" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,0,10,10">
            <Run Text="{Binding SrInstances.Count, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            <Run Text="Instances"  />
        </TextBlock>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Truth be told, I think the easiest way to do this would be to create a custom `ItemsPanel` which inherited from `WrapGrid`, but added a property to do this (upon item selected, show the assigned content template in a row/column which spans the width/height of the grid closest to the center).

Comment: @NateDiamond You are probably right.  Why don't you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Truth be told, I think the easiest way to do this would be to create a custom `ItemsPanel` which inherited from `WrapGrid`, but added a property to do this (upon item selected, show the assigned `ContentTemplate` in a row/column which spans the width/height of the grid closest to the center).

Answer (score 0):

How many items will you be displaying in the sub list? I don't think your GridView will look uniformed. What you can do is bind a ListView to your GridViewItem Data Template. Check out Microsoft's [WinRT Sample Code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples). It should have a multi-list GridView Sample or point you in the right direction.

Best of Luck

Comment: The number of items is variable (could be 1 or 2 up 20 to 30).  The `GridView` would look fine since the list would fill an entire row, pushing the other items down.  I cannot put the `ListView` in the `GridView.ItemTemplate` because the list would not span the whole row.  There is no-multi-list GridView sample in the link you supplied.